# Differential equation, tricky

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve the following:
$(x^2-y^2)dy+(y^2+x^2y^2)dx=0$?

Here is what I did:
$\frac{dy}{dx}(x^2-y^2)=-(y^2+x^2y^2)$

Dividing through, to leave differential on one side:
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-(y^2+x^2y^2)}{x^2-y^2}$

I then proved this is a homogeneous differential equation.
This is how I Proved it:
Let $A(x,y)=-y^2-x^2y^2$. $A(tx,ty)=-t^2y^2-t^2x^2t^2y^2$ When you factorize, you get:
$t^2A(x,y)$
Do the same for the denominator, and make the conclusion that these are homogeneous.
Is this right?
I let $y=vx$ so that $\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{dv}{dx}+v$

However I get stuck from here, as the equation seems to not make sense for.
Anyone to please guide me

Comment: Can you show the proof that the equation is homogeneous?

Comment: That is how I showed it

Comment: Your understanding of homogeneous function is not correct. $A(x,y)$ is homogeneous if $A(tx, ty) = t^n A(x,y)$ for some integer $n$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) for the definition.

Comment: Sorry, I made the necessary edits.... Was tardy. I proved it's homogeneous for $n=2$... How would I go about the solution

Comment: A homogenous differential equation can be written in the form $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(\frac{y}{x})$ i.e. if you scale the inputs $x$ and $y$ by some constant $t$, then the ODE is unchanged since the $t$'s will cancel. Here, if we divide your fraction on the top and bottom by $x^2$ we can see that it cannot be written in terms of $\frac{y}{x}$ alone.

Comment: I don't get that. Does that mean this D.E isn't solvable?

Comment: @Cornelia Katjiuongua Nope, it's just that it is not homogenous. Some other method might have to be used..

Comment: Doesn't appear to be doable by hand.

Comment: "When you factorize, you get: $t^2A(x,y)$" -> No, because the second term has $t^4$.

Comment: So any idea as to how I would solve it?

Comment: There is misconception with the terminology here. The question states "homogeneous differential equation" which it clearly is (no need to prove) [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation) . What @Infinity_hunter states is true for the wording "homogeneous function" but it is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(x^2 - y^2\right)dy = \left(y^2 + x^2y^2\right)dx
$$
This becomes
$$
\left(\frac{x^2}{y^2} - 1\right)dy = (1+x^2)dx
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{\frac{x^2}{y^2} - 1}{1+x^2}
$$

If we assume that $y = xt^a$ we have
$$
\frac{d}{dy} = \frac{dt}{dy}\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{1}{at^{a-1}x}\frac{d}{dt}
$$
Subbing into the original ode.
$$
\frac{1}{at^{a-1}x}\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{t^{-2a} -1}{1+x^2}
$$

This becomes separable
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{x}dx = at^{a-1}(t^{-2a} - 1)dt
$$

$$
\ln x + \frac{x^2}{2} = \int at^{-a - 1} -at^{a-1}dt
$$
setting $a = 1$
$$
\int t^{-2} -1dt = -t^{-1} - t + C
$$
Thus we have
$$
\ln x + \frac{x^2}{2} = - \frac{t^2 + 1}{t} + C
$$
converting back we have $y = xt$
$$
\ln x + \frac{x^2}{2} = -\frac{\frac{y^2}{x^2} + 1}{y/x} + C
$$

#### Shorter approach

$y = xt$

We then have
$$
(x^2 - x^2t^2)dy = (x^2t^2 + x^2x^2t^2)dx\\
x^2(1- t^2)dy = x^2t^2(1 + x^2)dx
$$
We then have
$$
\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}dy = (1+x^2)dx
$$

$$dy = \frac{dy}{dt}dt = xdt$$
Then we have
$$
\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}xdt = (1+x^2)dx \implies \frac{1-t^2}{t^2}dt  = \frac{1+x^2}{x}dx
$$

Comment: I do not get your manipulations. What are you claiming is the solution?

Comment: I am suggesting $$\ln x + \frac{x^2}{2} = -\frac{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + 1}{y/x} + C$$. Though still need to take the derivative to show that it is a solution. But which manipulation that you don't get? there could be a typo/error.